# Jmeter - wait for a specific response and collect total response time

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, beanshell

our application is testing file upload and I'm curious if I can make Jmeter wait for a specific response and then report collective time.

What I have now is:

```
whileLoop()
  -- HTTP Sampler
  -- JSON Extractor
```

JSON Extracor pulls out a specific field and if it's not `null` then the loop stops.

The problem is that JMeter doesn't report response time as a sum of all the responses (response times) it had to make and that is what I'm looking for. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this code inside a [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) .

You should get what you want.

Comment: also check "Generate parent sample" in Transaction controller

Comment: I don't think it's needed